# Hard Realtime C++ for Robot Control

Tags: c++, embedded, real-time, robotics

I am trying to control a robot using a template-based controller class written in c++. Essentially I have a UDP connection setup with the robot to receive the state of the robot and send new torque commands to the robot. I receive new observations at a higher frequency (say 2000Hz) and my controller takes about 1ms (1000Hz) to calculate new torque commands to send to the robot. The problem I am facing is that I don't want my main code to wait to send the old torque commands while my controller is still calculating new commands to send. From what I understand I can use Ubuntu with RT-Linux kernel, multi-thread the code so that my getTorques() method runs in a different thread, set priorities for the process, and use mutexes and locks to avoid data race between the 2 threads, but I was hoping to learn what the best strategies to write hard-realtime code for such a problem are.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "CONTROLLER.h"
#include "llapi.h"

void main{
    ...
    CONTROLLERclass obj;
    ...
    double new_observation;
    double u;
    ...
    while(communicating){
        get_newObs(new_observation); // Get new state of the robot (2000Hz)
        obj.getTorques(new_observation, u); // Takes about 1ms to calculate new torques
        send_newCommands(u); // Send the new torque commands to the robot
    }
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard real-time code generally avoids using mutexes and locks, because there is no way to guarantee that the locking of a mutex won't take more time than your real-time thread can afford to spend waiting.  If you need guaranteed real-time behavior (and not just "best effort"), then you'll need to use lock-free data structures instead (maybe you can get away with just using e.g. `std::atomic<double>` and similar)

Comment: This sounds like a very strange definition of "hard realtime". To me that's nanosecond accuracy or at least microseconds. If you are using Linux fluff and UDP you have very relaxed real-time requirements.

Comment: @Lundin Let's say I use Xenomai to take care of scheduler latency. I am not sure what I can do about UDP latency, but I do have an idea of how long the communication will take. But I do get your point that it's still not hard real-time requirements. Still, how do I make my implementation as best as I can?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I see you mean something similar to Jerry's solution. But as my comment says, the object I am using, I am not sure if I can use it as an atomic.

Comment: The traditional way would be to place all the real-time sensitive parts inside a MCU and then communicate from that one to the Linux fluff, using whatever communication interface that would be convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first of all, it sounds to me like you need to deal with the fact that you receive input at 2 KHz, but can only compute results at about 1 KHz.

Based on that, you're apparently going to have to discard roughly half the inputs, or else somehow (in a way that makes sense for your application) quickly combine the inputs that have arrived since the last time you processed the inputs.

But as the code is structured right now, you're going to fetch and process older and older inputs, so even though you're producing outputs at ~1 KHz, those outputs are constantly being based on older and older data.

For the moment, let's assume you want to receive inputs as fast as you can, and when you're ready to do so, you process the most recent input you've received, produce an output based on that input, and repeat.

In that case, you'd probably end up with something on this general order (using C++ threads and atomics for the moment):

```cpp
std::atomic<double> new_observation;

std::thread receiver = [&] { 
    double d;
    get_newObs(d);
    new_observation = d;
};

std::thread sender = [&] {
    auto input = new_observation;
    auto u = get_torques(input);
    send_newCommands(u);
};
```

I've assumed that you'll always receive input faster than you can consume it, so the processing thread can always process whatever input is waiting, without receiving anything to indicate that the input has been updated since it was last processed. If that's wrong, things get a little more complex, but I'm not going to try to deal with that right now, since it sounds like it's unnecessary.

As far as the code itself goes, the only thing that may not be obvious is that instead of passing a reference to `new_input` to either of the existing functions, I've read new_input into variable local to the thread, then passed a reference to that.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help! Now that I have read a bit about atomics, I realize I might have left out some details that I thought were not insignificant but might be in this case. the new_observation is an Eigen object of length 72 and u of length 20. And just out of curiosity, would it be the same if the observations were slower than my controller?

Comment: then I guess my best bet will be to use mutex and do priority inheritance to avoid priority inversion? Or would you suggest another way?

Comment: How about... use a lock-free queue and then memcpy the Eigen data into the queue and provide Map<> on the other side?

Comment: @skywalker: I'd just put the input into a structure. If copying them gets too slow, just put a pointer to the data in the queue. First cut would use equal priority for the threads, so priority inversion isn't an issue. With one producer and one consumer, you probably don't have enough contention for lock-free to buy you much. It does guarantee forward progress, but for real-time that's not a big win in itself.